# Making a function which changes the x,y values in a method

Tags: methods, f#

I am very new to object oriented programming. I have to make a method which moves my drone closer to it's destination however I can't seem to make it work. I have added my code, I have tried to access the first and second value in my tuples position and destination. But this code gives me errors saying that position and destination is not mutable. What am I doing wrong?

````
module Drones 
type Drone(x1:int, y1:int, x2:int, y2:int, spd:int) =
    let mutable position = (x1,y1)
    let mutable destination = (x2,y2)
    let mutable speed = spd
    member x.fly (position,destination) =
        if fst destination - fst position > 0 then position <- (x1+1,y1)
        else if snd destination - snd position > 0 then position <- (x1,y1+1) ```
````

Comment: Can I ask why you're doing object-oriented programming in a functional language if it's not because you're already familiar with it?

Comment: The immediate problem is that the method arguments are shadowing the object fields, but it's not clear why you're passing them in as arguments. Are they the same as the object fields? If so, you can just remove the arguments.

Comment: I am doing object-oriented programming for an assignment for uni. And thank you it seems that removing the arguments removed the errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
module Drones 

type Drone(x1:int, y1:int, x2:int, y2:int, spd:int) =
    let mutable position = (x1,y1)
    let mutable destination = (x2,y2)
    let mutable speed = spd
    member x.fly pos dest =
        if fst dest - fst pos > 0 then position <- (x1+1,y1)
        else if snd dest - snd pos > 0 then position <- (x1,y1+1)
```

Or maybe better to remove the parameters from the `fly` method:

```
type Drone(x1:int, y1:int, x2:int, y2:int, spd:int) =
    let mutable position = (x1,y1)
    let mutable destination = (x2,y2)
    let mutable speed = spd
    member x.fly () =
        if fst destination - fst position > 0 then position <- (x1+1,y1)
        else if snd destination - snd position > 0 then position <- (x1,y1+1)
```